# How can I check that a HTML fragment is valid using Rspec?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

Say I have a view helper that outputs something like this as a string:

```
'<div class="tag"><a href="posts/tagname"Tagname</a></div>'
```

How can I do something like this in Rspec?

```
the_string.should be_valid_html
```

I have looked at [be_valid_asset](https://github.com/unboxed/be_valid_asset), but it requires a network connection to hit the W3C servers and this really isn't necessary (plus it mangles the CI server). All I need is to make sure it isn't missing an angle bracket or something. Regexp seems like the wrong solution for parsing HTML (yes, I've seen *that* answer).

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't used it, here's a gem that claims to do what you're looking for:

https://github.com/ericbeland/html_validation

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but I don't think it's necessary to write tests for such details in view. Too much tests to write otherwise.

If all you need to is to ensure no missing bracket, I would suggest you to use `Haml` or `Slim` for templating. Any errors will be thrown and you don't even have a chance to write brackets in most cases.